# very slow with tor and VPN how do i improve speed and security please?

Tags: security, vpn, speed

Hi I have a very slow connection with tor and vpn can u suggest ways to improve both please ?

after that I will do more searches

paul

Answer (score 0):

Using Tor alone without a VPN probably will be faster. The Tor Project [recommends against](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/org/teams/CommunityTeam/Support#CanIuseaVPNwithTor) using a VPN with Tor unless you're an advanced user who knows how to configure both in a way that doesn't compromise your privacy. VPNs [have a single point of failure](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#IsTorLikeAVPN): the VPN provider. When you use a VPN, over time, websites still can build up a persistent profile of your usage. Even though sites you visit won't automatically get your originating IP address, they still know how to profile you based on your browsing history. Improve your anonymity and safety by using a [Tor pluggable transport](https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/circumvention.html).

Comment: Thank you so much Guentlebarrk, I shall try what u said and try again. I also like to have an untraceable email with gmail but i don't seem to manage this without a valid phone that is in my country, any ideas or should i keep on researching?  Regards Paul G.